# Is there such a colocation as "Dei Canet" and what does it mean?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, names

The Russian author Alexander Grin has a short story called "Blind Dei Canet." Dei Canet is a character's name, and it sounds Latin to me. I would like to know what Dei Canet can possibly mean.

A gut feeling tells me that "Dei" could be related to "God" (cf. *Vox Populi, Vox Dei*), but the placement doesn't make sense, especially because the dictionaries tell me that *canet* means *trumpet*? (Canet Dei??)

Thus, I am lost. Would a valid translation be "God intones" or something like this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty convinced that the relation to the two Latin words *Dei* (genitive singular of *Deus* = "God's/of God") and *canet* (future indicative of *cano* = "he/she will sing") is accidental.

Besides the fact that the phrase doesn't make any grammatical sense alone, another reason for thinking this isn't intended is in the spelling of the name as "Дей" (Dey) rather than "Деи." The latter, with two syllables, is the usual Russian transcription of the Latin word Dei (see for instance, the [Russian article on Opus Dei](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81_%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B8)), and accurately captures the fact that this isn't a diphthong. "Дей" is pronounced like the English word "Day" and would be a poor transcription of the Latin word.